# Mouse Events with Locked Computer

Tags: python, winapi, python-3.x, pywin32, python-3.4

I am running my script once every X hours with Python, this is done via RDP.  After I close out the RDP (I assume) the screen "locks" on the computer.  When trying to move my mouse with the following code I get an error

```
def mclick(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

The error I get when the script runs after I have closed the RDP connection:

```
File "x", line x, in mclick
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
```

I assume this is because the RDP connection has closed so it has no where to click, aside from constantly having this RDP connection alive how would I get this to run?

Comment: Maybe look for a Windows API call to wake up / unlock the computer before running the script?

Comment: @merlin2011 Were such a function to exist, what would that say about the security of the lock screen?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Very good point. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls to `SetCursorPos` fail when the workstation is locked. That is by design, and is a security feature. You simply need to catch and ignore the errors.

Comment: Unfortunately moving the mouse is required, to get around this I setup a server rdp-ing in from outside, and did an idle mouse move I found in another one of your answers to prevent it from locking. Thanks.